# Не работает функция вычисления НОД "Пузырьком"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Основной файл

```
import supportlib

def multipliers(number, all = None):
    list_multipliers = []
    if all:
        for n in range(1, number + 1):
            if number % n == 0:
                list_multipliers.append(n)
        return list_multipliers
    else:
        n = 2
        while number != 1:
            if number % n == 0:
                list_multipliers.append(n)
                number = number / n
            else:
                n += 1
        return list_multipliers

def lcm(arg):
    if type(arg) == list:
        for n in range(len(arg)):
            arg.insert(n, multipliers(arg.pop(n)))
        while arg.count(1) == len(arg) - 1:
            for tag in range(len(arg) - 1):
                list_mul = []
                for a in range(len(arg[tag])):
                    for b in range(len(arg[tag + 1])):
                        if (arg[tag])[a] == (arg[tag + 1])[b]:
                            list_mul.append((arg[tag])[a])
                arg.pop(tag)
                arg.insert(tag, 1)
                arg.pop(tag + 1)
                arg.insert(tag + 1, list_mul)
        print(arg)
        print(arg[-1])
        return supportlib.mul(arg[-1])
```

supportlib.py

```
def mul(list_of_numbers):
    return_number = 1
    for n in range(len(list_of_numbers)):
        return_number = return_number * int(list_of_numbers[n])
    return return_number
```

Не работает функция `lcm()`. `print(lcm([6, 10, 12]))` выводит:

```
[[2, 3], [2, 5], [2, 2, 3]]
[2, 2, 3]
12
```

Желаемое поведение:

1. Получает на вход (пока что) список с int-данными
2. Каждый int раскладывает на множители и записывает вместо этого int множители в качестве списка
3. Берёт по очереди n и n + 1 списки из большого списка
4. n-элемент меняет на единицу, n + 1 элемент меняет на список общих чисел в n и n + 1
5. Повторяет так со всеми элементами
6. Перемножает элементы в списке расположенном в конце большого списка

Короче говоря это НОД, сделанный через своеобразный "пузырёк". Но почему-то он не работает.

Comment: вы неправильно делаете. Нужно из каждого списка брать только те элементы, которые есть во всех списках, и потом их перемножить. Т.е. в приведенном примере нужно из каждого списка брать только 2.

Comment: @Эникейщик, это долго. Вот для этого и нужен пузырёк - машина считает только два элемента одновременно. Но в любом случае, если я сдвигаю общие множители списком в конец, то это ни на что не влияет. Я же в конце функции перемножаю числа из самого последнего списка. А если вы про то, что у меня идёт не всё сразу - то это сочетательный закон: a * b * c * d = ((a * b) * c) * d.

Comment: я ничего не понял из вашего комментария. Но в любом случае, если у вас получается какой-то последний список, то в вашем примере в нем должно быть только 2. А у вас 2, 2, 3. Очевидно, что ваш алгоритм неверный.

Comment: @Эникейщик, вот пример работы: 1) Вход: [6, 8, 12] 2) [[2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 3]] 3) [1, [2], [2, 2, 3]] 4) [1, 1, [2]] 5) Выход: 2 | Вот так должно обрабатываться. P. S. Извините за формат, с телефона пишу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фух, я доделал этот ужОс. Пользуйтесь на здоровье!

```
def lcm(arg):
    if type(arg) == list:
        for n in range(len(arg)):
            arg.insert(n, multipliers(arg.pop(n)))
        while arg[-2] != 1:
            for tag in range(len(arg) - 1):
                list_mul = []
                for a in range(len(arg[tag])):
                    for b in range(len(arg[tag + 1])):
                        if (arg[tag])[a] == (arg[tag + 1])[b]:
                            list_mul.append((arg[tag])[a])
                            (arg[tag])[a], (arg[tag + 1])[b] = 1, 1
                arg[tag], arg[tag + 1] = 1, list_mul
        return supportlib.mul(arg[-1])
```

Comment: А зачем? Вы считаете `НОК` сложно и медленно. А можно считать быстро и просто через алгоритм Евклида. Или вовсе вызвать `math.lcm`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, во-первых, я делаю продвинутый аналог math. Во-вторых, Евклид он конечно хорош, но в моей программе поменяется только самая нижняя if-ка, и я запишу не сравнение, а разность. Основной смысл в том, чтоб сделать "пузырьком", что, разумеется медленнее, но гораздо и менее требовательно к ресурсам ПК.